# Play a sound depending  on which image is clicked

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to make my application play a sound when I click on the picture drawn in the `Array`. What I want to do is play a different sound when you click a different picture.

This my Java code so far:

```
public class gorendis extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{
    private ImageView play;
    private ImageView a2;
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.huruf);

        play=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.a1);
        a2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.a2);
        //gambar=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.gambar);

        //gambar.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1);

        play.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                play();
            }
        });

        a2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                play();
            }
        });

        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        stop();
    }

    private void stop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private void play() {
        mp.start();
        play.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void loadClip() {
        try {
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.doajodoh);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            goBlooey(t);
        }
    }

    private void setup() {
        loadClip();
        play.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void goBlooey(Throwable t) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Exception!")
               .setMessage(t.toString())
               .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
               .show();
    }
}
```

Main layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="53px"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/a1" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="53px"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/a2" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView ...

    ..
>
  <LinearLayout
  ...
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/a1" android:id="@+id/play" android:layout_height="53px" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:background="@android:color/transparent" ></ImageView>
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/a2" android:id="@+id/a2" android:layout_height="53px" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:background="@android:color/transparent" ></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

Comment: This is unreadable, post your logCat in your original post

Comment: I do not see the edit button to change my post, sorry I was new here so not many understand .. can you help me?

Comment: It should be there, ctrl-f edit, we need your logCat too

Comment: see, I fail to add my xml code here..

Comment: what erros you are getting in logcat?

Comment: update this code **play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            play();
        }
    });** by this  `play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
             final MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.doajodoh);
    mp.start();
            }
        });` might it help.

Comment: there just some examples of program code, which I want to do is use more picture and sound but I do not understand how to make the code, I want to do that if I click on the image "a" then the sound that plays is "a" and if I click on the image "b" then the sound that plays is "b" and so on, if anyone can help me?

Comment: @android xx : when I try tu use your code then I get this error

[The Method create(Context, int) inthe type MediaPlayer is not appliceable for the arguments(new View,.OnClickListener(){},int)]

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to play different sounds on buttonclick, then i would advise this:

- Use the `setTag()` method of your buttons. Like `button1.setTag(0);`
  or `button1.setTag("guitarmusic");`
- You will notice that the `View.OnClickListener's` `onClick()` method
  gets a `View` as parameter.
- You know, that you set this `OnClickListener` only to buttons, so you
  can cast this `View` in the `onClick()` method to `Button` like
  `Button clicked = (Button) view;`
- Then you can access the tag, you set earlier to your buttons, and
  cast them too, like: `Integer buttonTag = (Integer)
  clicked.getTag();`
- Then you can decide in a simple [switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), wich sound you want to
  play, like: `switch(buttonTag){case 0: play first sound... break;
  ...}`

This way you wont need a separate OnClickListener to every sound you want to play :)

Comment: bali182: thanks for your advise can you help me in my other problem here ?
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806745/how-to-create-button-to-control-backsound-apps-android-source)

Comment: i didn't really understand the problem, but i tried my best :)

Answer (score 1):

finaly I found this sollution.. 
THIS WORK AND EVEN WITH THE LONG CODE !!

```
public class part1 extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private ImageView a2;
    private ImageView a3;
    private ImageView a4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        a2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.a2);
        a3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.a3);
        a4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.a4);

        a2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                a2();
            }               
        });
        setup();

        a3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                a3();
            }               
        });
        setup2();
        a4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                a4();
            }
        });
        setup3();

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        stop();
    }

    private void stop() {
        mp.stop();

    }

    private void a2() {
        mp.stop();
        loadClip();
        mp.start();

        a2.setEnabled(true);
    }
    private void a3() {
        mp.stop();
        loadClip2();
        mp.start();

        a3.setEnabled(true);
    }
    private void a4() {
        mp.stop();
        loadClip3();
        mp.start();

        a4.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void loadClip() {

        try {
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a2);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            goBlooey(t);
        }
    }
    private void loadClip2() {

        try {
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a3);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            goBlooey(t);
        }
    }

    private void loadClip3() {

        try {
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a4);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            goBlooey(t);
        }
    }

    private void setup() {
        loadClip();
        a2.setEnabled(true);
    }
    private void setup2() {
        loadClip2();
        a3.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void setup3() {
        loadClip3();
        a4.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void goBlooey(Throwable t) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder
            .setTitle("Exception!")
            .setMessage(t.toString())
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
            .show();
    }
```